# Call function in angular controller after clickin on a dynamiclly created element in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I want to call a function after clicking on a button which is added to dom after angular is loaded. I dont know if this is possible in the way  I am trying it, but I do know that my current code doesn't call the alert function.

After sending a search request to my backend, I get a list data entrys, which I display as hrefs.

```
        my_form.setAttribute("href", result[i].url)
        my_form.setAttribute("ng-href",'#here')
        my_form.setAttribute("ng-click", "alert(1)")
        my_form.setAttribute("style", "display:block;")
```

results in

```
<a href="/#/person/367" ng-href="#here" ng-click="alert(1)" style="display:block;">John Doe</a>
```

**Complete Code:**

```
var appModule = angular.module('graph', [])
appModule.controller('graphCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function ($scope, $http, $compile) {
$scope.search = function () {
    var data = {

    }

    $http.get('/api/search/?q=' + $scope.searchfield, data).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        var result = data;

        var searchResultsContainer = document.getElementById("dropdownId");
        while (searchResultsContainer.firstChild) {
            searchResultsContainer.removeChild(searchResultsContainer.firstChild);
        }
        for (i in result) {


            var my_form = document.createElement("a"); 
            my_form.setAttribute("href", result[i].url)
            my_form.setAttribute("ng-href",'#here')
            my_form.setAttribute("ng-click", "alert(1)")
            my_form.setAttribute("style", "display:block;")
            my_text = document.createTextNode(result[i].caption)

            my_form.appendChild(my_text)

            searchResultsContainer.appendChild(my_form)

        }
    })
}

  $scope.alert = function(){
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach of manipulating the dom in an angular app is all wrong. All you need is to pass the response to a scope property and let angular templating manage the dom such as with `ng-repeat`

Comment: Thanks that helped! :-)